# Xamarin XAML Formatting on Visual Studio Mac OS doesn't seem to work

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Has anyone else come across this with the latest release of VS (Sept 2019).

Previously going to Edit > Format Document would neatly format and order all the attributes of my XAML for the last couple of months. But now starting with the latest release, no matter what I select in the options the XAML no longer formats. The result is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <renderers:CustomFrame xmlns:renderers="clr-namespace:Japanese.Renderers" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Japanese.Templates.WordFrame" CornerRadius="{DynamicResource FrameCornerRadius}" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource WordBackgroundColor}" Elevation="{DynamicResource FrameElevation}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="{DynamicResource FrameBorderPadding}" HasShadow="true" Margin="15,0" ShadowColor="{DynamicResource FrameShadowColor}" />
```

With everything on one line, no matter how many times I go to options and select a custom format

Here's what my XAML is like before formatting:

[image]

Menu selection:

[image]

After formatting it's no longer putting attributes on new lines like it  should:

[image]

Comment: Hi , do you mean this version (*Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3.0*) ? You can show a screenshot about xaml .

Comment: I am having the problems on VS 8.3 after upgrading.  At one point when I was setting up the options it made VS hang and I had to force quit VS.

Comment: Maybe have a try with restarting VS or rebooting Mac .If also occurs , you can submit to [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) as an issue .

Answer (score 6):

Format Document with "Attributes in new line" / "attribute on a separate line":

Visual Studio for Mac 8.3:

Preferences > Source Code > Code Formatting > XML document > XML Format > Attributes in new line

Visual Studio 16.2.4:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > XAML > Formatting > Spacing > Attribute Spacing > Position each attribute on a separate line

Comment: I wish it worked but it doesn't work for me in Mac 8.3

Comment: Some suggestions: Does it work in a non-custom xaml? Is the property of the file xaml (although I suspect for Mac, Visual Studio formats the file based on the content header due to the available preferences (XML instead of XAML)? Tried reinstalling?

Answer (score 1):

Format document wouldn't be functional for xaml files. You can use xaml styler on vs for mac:

http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/382

or

You can download console project. After downloading console project and extracting directory, run this command "mono --arch=32 xstyler.exe"(you must already have mono and environment path must have been already set), then start the styler:

https://github.com/Xavalon/XamlStyler/releases/download/3.0/XamlStyler.Console-3.0.0.zip

Comment: Thanks sermet, I will check that out.  There is a code formatting XAML tab in the options but I cannot get that to work in fact when I used it and clicked okay my Visual Studio hung up and I had to Force Quit